# How to open web browser using selenium module in python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, selenium

I have the following code.I am trying to use selenium in python.

Code snippet:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser= webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('http://www.google.com/')
```

Error:

> C:\Users\xsat082\Desktop\fetchingurl>python fetchingsubdivurl.py
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "fetchingsubdivurl.py", line 5, in 
>       browser=webdriver.Chrome()
>     File "C:\Users\xsat082\Desktop\fetchingurl\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 68, in **init**
>       self.service.start()
>     File "C:\Users\xsat082\Desktop\fetchingurl\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
>       os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
>   selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver

Please suggest me how to overcome this issue?

Thanks
Simun

Comment: Hi Debanjan, I am running the python script on python2.7. (windows7 OS)following error has been observed.
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0

Comment: Also it opened the chrome but not the url i have entered on get().from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('user-agent = Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe')
driver.get('http://www.google.com ')
print("Chrome Browser Initialized in Headless Mode")
driver.quit()
print("Driver Exited")

Comment: This question was with respect to the error message **'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH**. Your current error seems to be **Service C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 0**. If your requirement have changed raise a new question as per your new requirement